# Can MongoDB potentially return the same document to two async calls of findOneAndUpdate({ field: { exists: false }})

Tags: mongodb

The goal is to never have two async calls of the function return the same document where the field sent doesn't exist.

I'm hoping that the document one call receives is then unable to be returned by another findOneAndUpdate call.

```
public getNextOpenDocument(data) {
  return this.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
    { data: { $exists: false } },
    {
      $set: {
        data: data
      }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside a transaction with snapshot read concern, I expect no.

Otherwise, I expect yes.